# Why TIdHTTP can't get a result correctly, but Postman can

Tags: delphi, https, get, idhttp

I have written a function in Delphi XE3 to get some data from the web using `TIdHTTP`. It can't get a result correctly, but postman can. Using a browser also returns data normally.

Can someone help here?

```pascal
procedure CreateHTTP(var vHTTP: TIdHTTP; var vSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL);
begin
  vHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  vSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(vHTTP);
  vSSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
  vSSL.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
  vHTTP.ProtocolVersion := pv1_0;
  vHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
  vHTTP.IOHandler := vSSL;
  vHTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100     Safari/537.36';
  vHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'text/plain';
end;

function HttpGetData(vUrl: String): String;
var
  lIdHttp: TIdHTTP;
  lSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  lDataStream: TStringStream;
  lCode: integer;
begin
  Result :='';
  CreateHTTP(lIdHttp, lSSL);
  lDataStream := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);
  try
    try
      lIdHttp.Get(vUrl, lDataStream);
      lCode := lIdHttp.ResponseCode;
      Result := lDataStream.DataString;
    except
      on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
      begin
        lIdHttp.Disconnect;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    lIdHttp.Disconnect;
    lDataStream.Free;
    lSSL.Free;
    lIdHttp.Free;
  end;
end;

lData := HttpGetData('https://emh5.eastmoney.com/api/CaoPanBiDu/GetCaoPanBiDuPart1Get?fc=30023602&color=w');
```

Comment: Please include the actual error message which occurs when the request fails with an error message. Otherwise, include the actual and expected response, if they are different.

Comment: Are you getting an exception raised? If so, what does it say? What is `ResponseCode` reporting? And why are you using a `TStringStream` instead of using the version of `Get()` that returns a `String`? Are you *sure* the server sends data as UTF-8?

Comment: ResponseCode is 200 ,no an exception raised,I also tested Unicode, ANSI, the same results

Comment: I mean the URL（https://emh5.eastmoney.com/api/CaoPanBiDu/GetCaoPanBiDuPart1Get?fc=30023602&color=w），Others URL are OK,the URL It is also available in the browser，But invalid in idhttp component .

Comment: You can use TRESTRequest. I can make you an example

Answer (score 0):

I saw here that this site requires TLS 1.2. At start, here it didn't worked too, but then i updated Indy to 10.6.2, ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll to newer versions and the worked well with TLS 1.2. Oh, i also changed the code here

```
vSSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2; //sslvTLSv1;
vSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];
```

Comment: i used ssleay32.dll(1.0.2.15),libeay32.dll(1.0.2.15) ,and idhttp is 10.6.2.5298 ,bug is  but it invalid